# Search on unicode strings using ADOQuery on NVarchar2 fields in ORACLE fails

Tags: delphi, oracle11g, delphi-xe2, ado, unicode-string

If ADOQuery is used to connect to ORACLE database using Oracle OLEDB provider search on unicode strings for NVARCHAR2 fields fails

In the Oracle (11g) database, there is a table like

```
create table unicodetest
(Code Number, Name NVarchar2(100))
```

Now I have inserted data into it
(done through sql developer)

```
insert into unicodetest 
values (1, N'ユニコード')
```

Now from delphi (XE2) application, I used TADOQuery to connect to ORACLE database using ORAOLEDB provider.

Now if I search for unicode string using following query

```
select * from unicodetest
where 
NAME like N'%ユニコード%'
```

It returns 0 records

tried with out using N but same result

Comment: I have not oracle at hand right now.. did you tried to pass the value as a parameter using ftWideString data type?

Comment: yes, even tried by passing the value as parameter using ftWideString, but that too didn't work